# How to access a function of a namespace from outside of application in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a namespace as shown below.

```
 namespace testnamespace
    {
        public class testclass : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            public static string testData;


            public void test()
            {
                string s = "fgdfgdg";

            }
            protected string Invoke(string methodname)
            {
                //string methodName = "test";
                string classname = methodname.Split('-')[0];
                 string funcname=methodname.Split('-')[1];
                 Type type = Type.GetType(classname); 
                Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                 MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(funcname);

             string result = (string)method.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(type), null);
             return result;
            }
            public static string testfunc(string temp)
            {
                hdnData = temp;           
               string strval=  Invoke(s);
               return strval;

            }
        }
    }
```

I am referencing this dll in another application like given below.

```
using testnamespace;
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           string test='testfunction';
            string s=testfunc(test);
        }
```

when I declare the function as public im getting error

> "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property "

but when i declare it as public static i can access the function but also all the other functions,variables are needs to be declared as static. **I dont want all the functions of that class to be static but only the function testfunc.** How can I do this?

Comment: No. This code throws error since i declare the function invoke as protected which is not allowed in static class.

Comment: `testclass.testfunc` should work with the above code - or, at least it should not result in said compilation error. If it's throwing an *Exception*, then include the exact exception and stack trace. Try this minimal code: `class A { public static string f () { return "foo"; } class B { void g () { A.f(); /* no problem, compiles fine */ } }` - perhaps the assembly wasn't updated or is being loaded from the GAC?

Comment: @user2246674 You didnt access any function from the static method f(). I modified your code which throws error for me.  class A
    { protected string ftest() { return "testf"; } public static string f() {string s = ftest(); return "foo";} class B  { public B(){A.f(); /* no prob */} }  }

Comment: @user1357872 Only *static methods* can be accessed (without an explicit instance receiver) from *static methods*. Why? Because there is no instance to invoke a non-static method from. That's just the end of the story. That is, the issue is *not* about calling a static method - I've shown that works, but is about trying to call a non-static method from a static method. This doesn't work and has nothing to do with being declared public. There are many similar posts that can be found my searching for the compiler error message.

Comment: why this is not accessible if im using the access modifier public?

Comment: This really looks like it should be solved with OO practices like interfaces, not reflection. The problems you're having come from bad class design, which would've shown already when just going the OO route. You do not need reflection and strings to call methods in other classes. You really hardly ever ever do.

Comment: @CodeCaster Please dont look at what is inside the function. I just add a piece of code from my application to shown up as an example. i am using Reflection  for another purpose in my application. If you feel this is not a good design suggest me so that atleast i can correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a static function you should specify the class name first. Otherwise the compiler would not know, which method to call. In your example replace:

```
string s=testfunc(test);
```

with

```
string s = testclass.testfunc(test);
```

You should also provide valid parameters, matching method's signature, when calling `method.Invoke(...)`, otherwise you will get a runtime exception.

And while i dont know, why one would create such a design (and you dont explain your idea behind your test class either), this looks like "bad" design to me.

Comment: can you please explain why do you think its a bad design?

Comment: @user1357872 i was referring to the way you use reflection in your `testclass.Invoke(string methodname)` method. There is nothing wrong with the way you use static methods